# Logback: Using different output files for different input files

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am working on an application, that converts data from different companies into corresponding xml-files. For logging I use logback. I have figured out, how i can write my logging information into a file. I would like to write to different files, depending on the file I am processing. Can this be done by just modifying the configuration file "logback.xml"?

Regards
Lars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender), the default configuration separates the logging based on a MDC value, which should be enough to cover your use case. For extended use cases there is also a [logging separation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html) chapter.